# Sublime Text - Find any text between two defined characters

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2

I am working on removing all of the css attributes in a stylesheet without removing the selector.

For example I want to take this:

```
.format-chat .chat .chat-timestamp {
    color: #722d19;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 5px 10px 0;
}
```

And turn it into this:

```
.format-chat .chat .chat-timestamp {
}
```

Since I am working with several thousand lines of CSS it would be nice to do somthing like this in one action, with a simple find and replace. In this case I want to find all text between curly brackets `{ }`.

Comment: Any attempt thus far?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can simply use the following regex to find everything inside `{` and `}`:

```
\{[^}]*\}
```

and replace with literal `{}`.

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively to @Sniffer's solution, you can:

1. Find all `{`'s (highlight one `{`, then `Alt+F3` or `Cmd+Ctrl+G` on mac)
2. Type `Ctrl+Shift+M` to select between all blocks (in this case, between `{}`'s)
3. Delete.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the {[^}]*} regex to find everything inside `{` and `}`:

1. First press ctrl + h for search and replace menu.
2. To enable Regular expression press Alt + R or press ".*" Option
   {[^}]*}
3. Search using {[^}]*} regular expression
   and replace with literal `{}`.
4. Replace with literal `{}`.

[Screenshot for above](https://pasteboard.co/Hy411I6.png)